# ATMEGA32 UART Communication

Tags: serial-port, avr, atmel, atmega, usart

I am trying to do serial communication in ATMEGA32 and I have a question:

In asynchronous serial communication both `UBRRH` and `UCSRC` registers have same location. I don't know which conditions that location will act as `UBRRH` and for which conditions, it will act as `UCSRC`.  I need different values for each register according to the work assigned to those registers

In the datasheet, they have mentioned the use of `URSEL` bit for selection betweem two registers but somehow I am not getting that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, the `URSEL` bit. According to the datasheet:

> When doing a write access of this I/O location, the high bit of the
>   value written, the USART Register Select (URSEL) bit, controls which
>   one of the two registers that will be written. If URSEL is zero during
>   a write operation, the UBRRH value will be updated. If URSEL is one,
>   the UCSRC setting will be updated.

This means, when you write to `UCSRC`, regardless of what value you want to put there, also set the `URSEL` bit (make sure that `URSEL` is `1`):

```
UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)| ... whatever else ...
```

When you write to `UBRRH`, make sure that `URSEL` bit must is zero. Here are some different ways of doing that:

```
UBRRH = (0<<URSEL)| ... whatever else ...  // just showing that URSEL isn't set
UBRRH = ...some value...                   // simple not setting URSEL
UBRRH = (someValue)&(~(1<<URSEL)           // Ensuring that URSEL isn't set
```

`URSEL` bit is just a high bit. So whatever value you write to `UCSRC`, set (turn on, make `1`) the high bit (bit 7). And when writing to `UBRRH`, make sure that bit 7 is cleared. Another way of thinking about it, every value you write to `UBRRH` must be under 128. And every value that you want to write to `UCSRC`, add 128 to it: this will turn on bit 7.  This is just as a way of explanation, the code above is clearer.

---

How is this done?  I don't know, I am not a uC designer. What seems likely is that the same IO location location is mapped to two different registers in the processor. Say you have a register named `foo`, and when you write a value to it the uC checks if the high bit is set. If it is it writes the value to internal memory location `1` and if it isn't it writes the value to internal memory location `2`.

---

If you are using the `URSEL` bit correctly, then the values are being written correctly. Your testing not showing the correct values because you are not reading them propertly. Page 162 of the datasheet:

> Doing a read access to the UBRRH or the UCSRC Register is a more
>   complex operation. How- ever, in most applications, it is rarely
>   necessary to read any of these registers.
>
> The read access is controlled by a timed sequence. Reading the I/O
>   location once returns the UBRRH Register contents. If the register
>   location was read in previous system clock cycle, reading the register
>   in the current clock cycle will return the UCSRC contents. Note that
>   the timed sequence for reading the UCSRC is an atomic operation.
>   Interrupts must therefore be controlled (for example by disabling
>   interrupts globally) during the read operation.

So when your read `UBRRH` / `UCSRC` for the first time you get `UBRRH`. If you *immediately* read again you read `UCSRC`. But as the documentation suggests, there is no real reason to read these registers. It seems that you do not trust the datasheet, but this is a mistake: the datasheet is the best source of information about such matters: without datasheets we would be nowhere.

Comment: BUT how can this happen since both registers have same locations then how can they have different values...........I have tried with URSEL =1 and 0 and debug the code, but when it is 0 then both registers got written the same value, but when it is 1, none of the registers got written..........UCSRC = UCSRC = (1<<URSEL) | (1<<UCSZ1) | (1<<UCSZ0) just simply do nothing in my AtmelStudio 6.0 debugger, though URSEL is set, but if it is 0 then both is written with th esame value.........

Comment: I am not making any offence, but still if u have got me wrong then i am sorry :).........i was debugging my code just to check whether all initializations have been done properly or not and in that case i am facing the above error so i am confused whether my code will gonna work or not..........:(........But as u have said i am gonna ask a new que for this :)