# ATMEGA32 usart setup assembly

Tags: assembly, serial-port, avr, usart

Hi I've been trying to implement serial communication using Atmel studio 6.1
and an ATMEGA32 mcu. 
I read the datasheet and the post:
[ATMEGA32 UART Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841050/atmega32-uart-communication)

I think I get more or less how it should be set but I'm not able to do it.
I set the value of the URSEL to 1 in order to write to it but when I run the simulation it doesn't seem to write it and when I write a 0 to it and write to UBRRH then I can see that both the UCSRC and the UBRRH are written with the same value.

here's a copy of the code...

```
 jmp RESET

 RESET:

    ldi r16, $12
    out UCSRA, r16
    ldi r17, $00
    ldi r16, $47

    out UBRRL,  r16
    out UBRRH,  r17
    ; Enable receiver and transmitter
    ldi r16,    (1<<RXEN) | (1<<TXEN)
    out UCSRB, r16

    ; Set frame format: 8 data, 1 stop bit
    ldi r16, (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<UCSZ1)
    out UCSRC, r16
    ldi r16, $80
    ldi r17, (0<<URSEL)
    out UBRRH,  r17
loop:
    ldi r16, $41
    jmp TX

TX:
    sbis UCSRA, UDRE
    rjmp TX
    ;move data to the buffer
    out UDR, r16
    jmp loop
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I can see some inconsistency in Your code. Did You read Atmega32 datasheet diligently, especially part about USART module SFRs?

```
ldi r16, $12
out UCSRA, r16
```

Why do You want to set FE bit (bit 4) in UCSRA? This is read-only bit, datasheet says: "Always
set this bit to zero when writing to UCSRA." Initial value of UCSRA is 0x20 and only bits 0, 1 and 6 are R/W, so write 0x22 to UCSRA to set U2X bit (I think this was Your intention).

```
ldi r16, $80
ldi r17, (0<<URSEL)
out UBRRH,  r17
```

I don't exactly understand above lines. You're writing something in r16 but never use it (You're write another char to r16 in next lines). Next You write 0 to r17 (`0<<URSEL` gives r17=0x00) and You store it in UBRRH. Why? You write 0x00 to UBRRH some lines above. You need to change URSEL only when You want to store something in UBRRH or UBRSC. So these 3 lines make no sense.

The code for init USART and sending char in loop should look like this:

```
INIT:
    ldi r16, $22
    out UCSRA, r16
    ldi r17, $00
    ldi r16, $47
    out UBRRL, r16
    out UBRRH, r17
    ldi r16, (1<<RXEN) | (1<<TXEN)
    out UCSRB, r16
    ldi r16, (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<UCSZ1)
    out UCSRC, r16
LOOP:
    ldi r16, $41
TX:
    sbis UCSRA, UDRE
    rjmp TX
    out UDR, r16
    rjmp LOOP
```

And one note if You're using simulation tools - they sometimes shows senseless results, don't believe it if You really don't understand what happens inside processor.